# What is the minimum age for publishing an audiobook on ACX?

Tags: publishing, young-author, audiobook

I am looking to publish an audiobook on ACX, and I am 13 years old. **Is there any age restriction on publishing an audiobook on ACX?** For example, during registration, it asks me if I hold a US tax ID for the payments from ACX.

Answer (score 3):

You must be 18 to publish on ACX.

But you can probably convince a parent/guardian to publish for you.

Amazon will also publish audiobooks, but you will still need a parent/guardian to publish for you since you are under 18.

Comment: How about having a fake author's name, like for ex. Jim Brown? How would that work?

Comment: First off: don't make fake IDs just to publish a book. I don't think that's what you're referring to, but in case it is, don't. But if you just want a pen name/pseudonym, you would probably put that in when it asks for pen name or something. Don't put in the pen name when it asks for your real name. I haven't used ACX, so I don't know what the publishing form looks like.

Comment: Oh, oh-oh, yea, I meant pen name. I didn't know what a pen name was once; then I searched it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are pretty good reasons for most age restrictions.

In creating a book, an author cannot help but reveal a great deal about their personal worldview, their values, their beliefs and their dreams.   At such a young age, most of that internal landscape is still evolving.  The next five years of your life may include massive changes to any or all of those elements and the sum of those changes may leave you far from the person you currently are.

In publishing a book today, you may permanently associate your name, your pen-name and your talent, with enthusiasms and values which some future you might not share.  If you are fortunate enough to succeed in earning a large following, that future you may resent being typecast by the words you've crafted today.

That you are already writing is spectacular!  If you keep it up and keep refining your abilities, you will have a major advantage over your peers when you all finally reach legal publishing age.  And more importantly, you will have five years of accumulated works, all meticulously reviewed, edited and finalized, ready all at once.

As a reader, compare the difference in experience between reading a trilogy in series over reading the first book of a trilogy and then waiting for years (or forever) for the second book.  Use the next five years to create a complete trilogy (or several) so that you can give your readers that complete trilogy experience on day one.

Above all else, Keep Writing!

Answer (score 0):

18 (or the legal age of majority) is the minimum. Minors aren’t able to enter contracts, which is required for publishing.

There are a number of [steps required for publishing](https://www.acx.com/help/legal-contracts/200485430), and the first is [opening an account](https://www.acx.com/help/account-holder-agreement/201481940): “To open an account on ACX, you must be a resident of the United States, the United Kingdom, Canada or the Republic of Ireland and be at least 18 years old or the legal age of majority in the jurisdiction in which you reside.”

I believe you can have your parent/guardian get your book published as an audiobook for you by giving them the [“Authority to Enter into this Agreement”](https://www.acx.com/help/ZXZ8Q2SFT6NQA2E). Still, I suggest contacting ACX support to ensure there are no legal problems.